# Fluid full width grid in container

Tags: css, grid, margin

What is a simple, preferrably css-only, solution to achieve the following:
Have a grid of divs with fluid widths that always matches the with of the container, without having some space on one side due to the margin of the divs.

All boxes should be in one container.

Here is what i have: https://jsfiddle.net/5g0uwxtx/

```
<div id="container">
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

```
#container{
width:100%;}
.box{
width: 32%;
height: 0;
padding-bottom: 32%;
float:left;
margin:0 1% 1% 0;
background-color:#CCC;}
```

I want each row of boxes to stretch exactly to the right side, without left over space.

Thanks!

Comment: "Best" solution? That's asking for opinions which is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: ok, edited. what i meant is: what is a simple, cross-browser solution that is preferrably css only.

Comment: Then your question is too broad and thus off-topic again. SO is for solving specific issues not general & vague requests that could be found with a google search.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways, but one of the more commonly seen is using a row based layout with `first-child` or `last-child` to control the margins, e.g.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MajyaG

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="row cf">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row cf">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
</div>

#container{

}

.box{
  width: 32.5%;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 32%;
  float:left;
  margin:0 1% 1% 0;
  background-color:#CCC;
}

.cf:before,
.cf:after {
    content: " "; /* 1 */
    display: table; /* 2 */
}

.cf:after {
    clear: both;
}

.row .box:last-child{
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention: the number of boxes in a row can vary, for example only two on smaller devices. So i would need a solution that has all boxes in one container.